# How do I create a SASI Cassandra instance in a Datastax Cluster

Tags: indexing, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Following the SASI creation docs on Datastax ([here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/refCreateSASIIndex.html)) for DSE v5.0.4, produces the error:

```
cqlsh:sandbox> SHOW VERSION
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.10.1443 | DSE 5.0.4 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]

cqlsh:sandbox> CREATE CUSTOM INDEX "sandboxTestIdx" on test (bop) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex';
ConfigurationException: Unable to find custom indexer class 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex'
```

Digging into SASI shows that it's only available 'out of the box' for Cassandra versions past 3.4, so my question is, how can I add SASI support to the latest version of DSE (v5.0.4)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can unless datastax releases a new version which uses cassandra 3.4 or later.

Or you can use the download the latest version of cassandra which support SASI but then you dont get the DSE features.

Comment: Confirmed via Datastax support, SASI may be incorporated into a future release of DSE but is currently unavailable.